# Off-by 1 Error in Project Euler 19

Tags: c++, math

I'm doing [Project Euler #19](http://projecteuler.net/problem=19). It's obviously a trivial problem if you just want to loop through month-by month and apply some high-school modular arithmetic but I'm trying a different approach just for fun.

I note that Jan/Feb 1 1901 are not Sundays, neither are Jan/Feb 1 2001, hence I can view my calendar year as starting on March 1. Using basic modular arithmetic, it's easily seen that if leap years didn't exist, then the number of Xdays in a given year is a repeating sequence {2,2,2,1,2,1,2} since 365 is congruent 1 (mod 7). So factoring a leap year results in a a 2 element jump in the sequence. So I've written this code to complete the problem:

```
const unsigned s[7] = {2,2,2,1,2,1,2};
unsigned n = 0;  
unsigned y = 1901;
unsigned c = 0;
do {
    c=c%7;
    n+=s[c];
    ++y; 
    c += ((y%4!=0)||(y%400==0) ? 1 : 2); 
} while (y<2001);
std::cout << n << std::endl;
```

However I'm getting 172 where the answer is 171. Anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Note: please don't leave 1200/7 comments.

FIXED: replacing with `c += ((y%400==0)||((y%4==0)&&(y%100!=0)) ? 2 : 1);`

Comment: Probably an issue with [your do while loop](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a8d4f159dc8507e9e365456159419745).

Comment: I don't have an answer. I could not understand your approach, but it seemed really interesting. Can you please explain this line: "number of Xdays in a given year is a repeating sequence {2,2,2,1,2,1,2}", or point me to a source for understanding this?

Comment: For one thing, your [leap year algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) is incorrect.

Comment: Your leap year calculations are a bit suspicious. 2000 was a leap year.

Comment: and yes, the problem is due to me misreading def of leap year lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: about the leap-year rule.

The leap year rule has just *one* more special case.

A year is a leap year if it is:

- Divisible by four

  - But not divisible by 100

    - Except when it is also divisible by 400

Sometimes I wish we had metric calendars.  Megaseconds and kiloseconds, anybody?

---

Maybe you got a bit confused about the leap-year rule?

From your link:

> A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.

So a year divisible by 400 *is* a leap year.  Your condition in your code is reversed.